# Align two similar audio wav files

Tags: algorithm, audio, signals, signal-processing, speech-recognition

I have two audio wav files and I have to align the similar or same content in both of these wav files. There can be extra content(content which is not present on another wav file) in any or both of the wav files.
I have tried it using DTW algorithm but DTW gives the mapping of even those components which are extra i.e present in only one wav file.

The input will be two audio wav files and the output will be the timestamps of the window of both the audios containing the aligned part.
There can be multiple alignments possible. Also, there can be a little noise in any of the wav files. Hence, there need not be a perfect alignment between the contents. However, the aligned contents should not be much dissimilar.

[image: Output of DTW]

Comment: Can the output contain more than one window of aligned content? Does aligned content have _exactly_ the same data in that portion?

Comment: @גלעדברקן , yes there will be multiple aligned contents as you can see in the above graph. The aligned content can be a little noisy so content has a little noise, it can be aligned if the noise is very less and is matching well with the content of other wav file.